# Access Server Object on Client Side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a object which gets populated on the server side. I want to access this object on Client side that is on aspx page ( using Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest thing you'll get to be able to access the "object" on the client side is to provide the object as JSON data, and then take it from there on the client side. However, speaking in general, you can't just send an object from the server and then have the client to work with that object.

Answer (score 1):

The server-side controls usually **change their ID** parameter a little when presented on the final generated ASPX page. So you could check what the ID is of a particular element on the generated ASPX page and use that to access your elements in JavaScript.

One way to do this is write JavaScript code like

```
  document.getElementbyId('<%=control.ClientID%>'). ...
```

Alternately, you could use the [**CssClass**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) attribute in the server-side and do a **getElementsByClassname** in Javascript, but that is more cumbersome than the above.

Answer (score 0):

No, once the information(html) is sent to client(response) you cannot access any objects on the server, except if you send a request to the server and get the response(via ajax, iframe or postback).

the other key thing is, browsers understand only text, html, css, js, json,xml and image binaries, untill otherwise there are addons which can read other formats, so if your server object cannot be transformed to any of these, you cannot even read that on the client.